# Laravel Session and multiple tabs

Tags: php, laravel, session, variables, logout

I found out very interesting (at least for me) session behaviour while I tested my "log out" section:

If I open two tabs in a browser and log in to my app with both of them (with same account credentials), then if I go to the first tab, press "log out" - it will remove my session variables and I will be logged out from both tabs. But when I do the opposite - if I log out from the second tab - the first tab remains logged in and my `Session::flush()` is not applying.

May someone explain that behaviour and tell me how to control that. I want to remove my session variables no matter which tab is "logged out", not only the first.

EDIT:

Now I am expecting another issue - no matter which tab i "log out" - the other still remains logged in. Is it related with caching or something?

Comment: strange, are you sure? the expected behavior is that the logout ends all sessions, so no matter how many tabs are open, all should be logged out once any of logout links are clicked

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior, but for some reason it applies only if I log out from my first tab. I tested this with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Browser tabs or new Windows  (File/New) share the same HttpSession assuming tabs are pointing to the same web app. This is expected behavior.

Comment: Now I am expecting another issue - no matter which tab i "log out" - the other still remains logged in. Is it related with caching or something?